# PHP errors written to wrong log

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cgi

My Linux server is running PHP 7 as a CGI on Apache2. In `php.ini` I have

```
error_log = /var/log/apache2/php.log
```

Now, I have two problems:

1) All PHP errors go to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` instead of `php.log`. I have edited the right `php.ini` because `ini_get('error_log')` returns the full path of `php.log` in PHP.

2) When I try to open either of those files in PHP, I get permission denied. I have `chmod`'d both files to 777, but PHP is still unable to access them.

The server has been restarted multiple times so the configuration changes apply. My Apache configuration is this:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

ScriptAlias /local-bin /usr/bin
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 php
Action application/x-httpd-php7 /local-bin/php-cgi7.0
<Directory "/usr/bin">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

How can I redirect PHP errors to the right file, and also make it readable for PHP? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` to `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php.log` ?

Comment: chmodding the files is usually not enough. you have to have permission to access ALL of the parent/container directories. granting access to a file is pointless if it's inside a locked back vault. The log files are created while apache's still running as root, therefore the files are owned by root. then once you try to access them in php, apache is not longer root, and php has no rights to the files.

Comment: Okay, back to the basics! It was indeed a permission issue with parent directories. Now I feel embarrassed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `owner` and the `group` of the log directory and the log file/s (if already exist/s) to `www-data`:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/log/directory
```

Dont change the directory permissions to `777` as it might cause security issues, use `775` instead. For the log files use `664`.

You might also want to add your system user to the group `www-data` if not already a member (use `groups` command to check for your existing groups), a system reboot is required after that for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo adduser user www-data #change 'user' to your
```

Comment: Thanks! You know, it's easy to stumble with this sort of stuff when you come from a Windows world and are familiar with NTFS. I forgot that execute permission is required on each parent directory to access the file. So eventually I created `/var/log/php`, `chown`'d it to `root:www-data` and `chmod`'d it to `750`. Then I could use `php.log` inside that folder. PS. I changed the permission to `777` only temporarily, don't worry :)